# r batch reading xls files from specific sheet

Tags: r, excel, batch-processing

I have around 30 excel files in my folder.

I am interested in reading them all.

I used this code below

```
library(readxl)
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
```

The problem is each excel file has multiple sheets and I am interested in the contents of only one sheet , sheetName = "Piano", not interested in the contents of other sheets.

So how can I ensure that in addition to reading all the 30 excel files r reads only data from sheetName="Piano" from all these excel files. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of the `sheet` argument of `read_excel`.  According to `?read_excel`

> sheet - Sheet to read. Either a string (the name of a sheet), or an integer (the position of the sheet). Ignored if the sheet is specified via range. If neither argument specifies the sheet, defaults to the first sheet.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
df.list <- map(file.list, read_excel, sheet = 'Piano')
```

Comment: as always akrun to the rescue